# How do you divide list into equal parts?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

I have a `list` such as:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Let's say I want to divide this `L` into 3 parts into something like:

```
result = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8]]
```

How can I do this without using higher programming methods (ONLY USING SIMPLE PYTHON METHOD)?

Comment: This is not homework by the way, it's part of final exam but I do not want to look at answers yet.

Comment: Also you cannot assume that there is 8 elements like above there can be 7 or 6 or whatever integer.

Comment: I've formatted this question for you but I still don't understand the last sentence. Also the three lists in your `result` list are not what I would call "equal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
In [13]: l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

In [14]: result = [l[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(l), 3)]

In [15]: result
Out[15]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

This pulls out slices from the list that are of length `n`, where `n` is the number that you add to `i` and is also the step value in your `range`. As @Eric pointed out, this breaks the list into chunks of three, but not three chunks. In order to get it into three chunks, you can do something like:

```
In [21]: l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

In [22]: chunk = int(round(len(l)/3.0))

In [23]: result = [l[i:i+chunk] for i in range(0,len(l),chunk)]

In [24]: result
Out[24]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]

In [25]: l = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [26]: chunk = int(round(len(l)/3.0))

In [27]: result = [l[i:i+chunk] for i in range(0,len(l),chunk)]

In [28]: result
Out[28]: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
```

As it sounds like you have certain constraints, this could be written in a `for` loop as well (although this actually has more function calls than the one above :) ):

```
In [17]: result = []

In [18]: for i in xrange(0, len(l), 3):
   ....:     result.append(l[i:i+3])
   ....:     
   ....:     

In [19]: result
Out[19]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: is there way other than using  result = [l[i:i+3]

Comment: @EricJung What are your constraints? Also, where are you running into issues?

Comment: I am trying to sliced this into 3 equal parts

Comment: Constraints without using any of those function calls beside for loop

Comment: @EricJung Hmm, well none of that (except for `range`) involves function calls - that is taking a slice from a list. Is that not allowed?

Comment: Yes without using slicing nor any of the imported program. How would you do it with only using range

Comment: @EricJung: What imported program?

Comment: like array or lambda stuff like that, I am a newbie, could someone please divide it without any complexity?? Thank you for your answer by the way.

Comment: Also, this code slices a list into chunks of 3, not 3 chunks.

Comment: OKAY I THINK I GOT IT THANKS ROCKET

Comment: @EricJung Hmm, no slices eh? That is a very bizarre constraint :) If you look at what it is doing, it is taking a slice of the list that starts at `i` and extends to `i+3`. To simulate this, you can have another `for` loop inside of the main loop that iterates from the current value of `i` to `i+3`, appending the list element at that position to an intermediate list, which is then added to the main list. I don't envy your task :)

Comment: @EricJung: This code does not use lambdas or np.array - what's the problem?

Comment: If you have a problem with slicing you should do the python tutorial.  You'll be better off for it in the end.

Comment: @Eric Great point - updated to reflect that (my attention to detail - not so good :) ).

Comment: @EricJung No problem, good luck with the exam :)

Answer (score 1):

RocketDonkey's answer should be fine.  Here's one without the list comprehension:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
result = {}
idx = 0
for i in l:
    group = idx/3
    if group not in result:
        result[group] = []
    result[group].append(i)
    idx += 1
result.values()


>>> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

`enumerate()` can be used to remove the manual idx increment.